# How can i use SingalR in JAVA

Tags: java, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I wanted to build SignalR Hub in JAVA, but i am unable to find related sdk jar files.

Can any body tells me from where i can get those jar files?
Is there any other java framework available for the same functionality?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use [atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). `SignalR` is developed for `c#` platform.I don't know whether you can use this on `JAVA`. If you are developing web site then you can use `socket.io`